# What does $\nabla f(x)^Tx$ mean geometrically?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, and $\nabla f(x)$ be $f$'s gradient at $x$, then what does $\nabla f(x)^Tx$ mean geometrically? Is it the "negative" intercept between the tangent plane through $x$ and the $z$-axis? Because I think $z=\nabla f(x)^T(x-x_0)$ is the tangent plane, so $z(0)=-\nabla f(x_0)^Tx_0$?

Comment: The directional derivative

Comment: I will add slightly to WalterJ's answer.  In spherical coordinates, with $r=|x|$, the function $(\nabla f(x),x)$ is simply $r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$, so it is a derivative of $f$ in the radial direction.